# Undefined 'this' on class extending from EventEmitter when trying to call emit method inside of class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use a custom event emitter to handle a webhook, but when calling a method from my class I always get 'this' as undefined

**serviceWebhook.js**

```
class WebhookHandler extends EventEmitter{
  constructor (){
    super();
  }
  receiver(req, res){
    try {
      res.sendStatus(200);
      if (req.body && req.body.action) {
        this.emit(req.body.action, req.body)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
module.exports = {
  WebhookHandler: WebhookHandler
}
```

**index.js**

```
var webhookh = new serviceWebhook.WebhookHandler();
router.post('/webhookendpoint', webhookh.receiver);
webhookh.on('action_one', function name(message) {
  console.log('EMITTED')
  console.log(message)
}
```

**This is the error I get:**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

**I have also tried this:**

```
super.emit(req.body.action, req.body)
```

But then I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of undefined

Comment: have a look at bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the receiver method of an instance of your WebhookHandler class to the callback of your router moves the lexical scope of the method.
Try: `router.post('/webhookendpoint', webhookh.receiver.bind(webhookh));`
This will bind the scope of this within the callback to that of your instance of WebhookHandler.

Comment: Thank you, using `router.post('/webhookendpoint',  (req, res) =>webhookh.receiver(req, res));` seems to work too